# If you figure out your own question yourself, should you take it off the site?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

If you ask a question that later you realize you know the answer to, should you remove that question from the site?

For instance, I asked a question about a game I was writing in Python but realized that there was a very simple solution to the problem.  Would it be better to take the question off the site, or leave it for others who have similar problems?

Comment: If it isn't a duplicate, answer it.

Comment: Except when it turns out to be a typo, then you should delete it.

Answer (score 3):

If you find the answer to your problem yourself and (as Matthew [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267209/if-you-figure-out-your-own-question-yourself-should-you-take-it-off-the-site#comment69750_267209)) it's not a duplicate and you think that others will come across the same problem, then post the solution as an answer yourself.

You can then accept the answer, but you don't get any rep for that.

Comment: If you leave your answer unaccepted, it might give motivation for someone to give a better answer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you. If you don't feel that it will be useful to other people, then you may delete it, but be careful about doing this too often, because deleting too many questions can lead to a question ban.

If, on the other hand, you feel that you're question and subsequent solution would be useful to future readers, then feel free to answer your own question.